# Reduce WAV file size using cscore library

Tags: cscore

I want to reduce WAV file using cscore libary without loosing audio, something like NAudio

var pcmStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(inputSteam);
 var wavCompressedStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(target, pcmStream);

Comment: A regular wav file containing pcm data can't be compressed without loosing quality. You can reduce samplerate, bits per sample or even the number of channels. But in the end, you'll loose quality.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but i don't see any option in cscore library to update these properties while creating WAV file using CSCore.Extensions.WriteToWaveStream

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can change the format of a wave file with by opening the existing audio data as `IWaveSource`, changing its format and writing it back to any stream or file.
For example:

```
IWaveSource waveSource = ...

waveSource
    .ToMono() //for example, convert to mono
    .ChangeSampleRate(44100) // specify samplerate
    .ToSampleSource()
    .ToWaveSource(16) //specify bits per sample
    .WriteToWavStream(stream);
```

But keep in mind that you probably will loose audio quality by downsampling, changing bits per sample, ...

Comment: It's working fine in windows server, but linux getting error Error Message: "COM is not supported" and Exception Type: "System.PlatformNotSupportedException". Any help? @Florian